# ReactiveMongo configuration on Heroku using Config Vars

Tags: scala, heroku

I have ReactiveMongo happily working with PlayFramework `("org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.4")` with the `mongodb.uri` configuration in my application.conf file.  This has been pushed up and works correctly with Heroku.  I also have an application.prod.conf working.

I am now trying to roll this out onto a Heroku Pipeline, with two upstream servers (so that prevents me continuing to use the application.prod.conf mechanism), and want to configure the mongodb.uri from Heroku's Config Vars.  I am not sure how to get ReactiveMongo to look for environment variables instead of application.conf settings.

I also don't know how to specify the uri to use in the code otherwise I could just use something like `val uri = scala.util.Properties.envOrElse("mongodb_uri", "some-value-here")`.  It seems to happen by ReactiveMongo magic (under the hood).

Or is there a different way to do it?!?!

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put environment variables in your `application.prod.conf`. For example:

```
mongodb_uri = ${?MONGODB_URL}
```

For more information see the [Play documentation on production configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using-environment-variables).